# When to use onclick ={ myfuntion()} vs onclick={() => (myfunction())}

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, state, use-state

Why is the id undefined in the randomCard function when using the onClick= {(randomCard()}
and defined  when using onClick = {() => (randomCard())}

```
function Home() {
    const [cardlist, setCardList] = useState([]);
    const navigate = useNavigate()
    
    function randomCard() {
        const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * cardlist.length);
        const id = cardlist[index].id;
        navigate(`/cards/${id}`)
    }  

    useEffect(() => {
        async function fetchData() {
            const res = await axios.get('https://db.ygoprodeck.com/api/v7/cardinfo.php');
            const results = res.data;
            setCardList(results.data);
            console.log(cardlist);
        }
        fetchData();
    }, [])

    return (
        <div className='home'>
            <h1>Welcome to the Yu-Gi-Oh Database</h1>
            <p>Choose Option</p>
            <div className="options">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href='/allcards'>Show All Cards</a></li>
                    <li><a href='/'>Search Card</a></li>                    
                    <li><a href='' onClick={() => (randomCard())}>Random Card</a></li>                    
                </ul>
               
            </div>
        </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: `onClick= {randomCard()}` calls `randomCard()` and assigns the return value to `onClick` whereas `onClick={() => (randomCard())}` assigns an anonymous function to `onClick` which is called ... on click. (Since you aren't passing any arguments you can just `onClick= {randomCard}` (no parentheses))

Comment: The one you didn't try was `onClick= {randomCard}`,  and that would avoid having to use an arrow function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One would only use something like

```
onClick={randomCard()}
```

when that function *returns a function*. This situation isn't uncommon, eg:

```
const makeHandleClick = (id) => () => {
  setClickedId(id);
};
```

```
onclick={makeHandleClick(id))
```

But it's a common mistake to use `onClick={randomCard()}` when you actually only want to run the function when the element is clicked - in which case that will run the function immediately, when rendered, instead of when it's clicked (and will often result in too many re-renders and an error).

Use

```
onClick={randomCard}
```

when you want the function to run when the element is clicked, and not when the element is rendered.

The above is often equivalent to

```
onClick={() => randomCard()}
```

Answer (score 0):

The key answer to your question is to understand the difference between:

- Calling `onClick={() => (randomCard())}` this is calling on request
- Execute `onClick= {randomCard()}` and this is just execution immediately

I suggest you research a bit so it would be clearer to You, but in a nutshell, `onClick={() => (randomCard())}` this get's called when you click it and `onClick= {randomCard()}` this gets called when the file is loaded.

When you use "Execute" your data will not be fetched, and the function will be called before setCardList is assigned value to cardList.
But when you use "Calling" your data is already fetched, and cardList is holding an array of data.

I hope I did not confuse you, just do a little research and you will get it, it is very much simple, just need to get the flow of rendering the component.

Comment: Exactly. `() => randomCard` is setting the click to an anonymous function that will return the function it's handling. `randomCard()` would return the value from it immediately, because with the anonymous function or referential function, you're passing it the reference to the function to call later; not the value itself.

Answer (score 0):

In React, the value of `onClick` must be a **callback that returns something ( void )** :

```
onClick={() => { 
    console.log('clicked')}
}
```

So when passing `functions()` as a value to onClick, it’ll run when the component renders.
In your case, `onClick={randomCard()}` will run before data fetching happens, which means the card's `id` is rather `undefined`.
The example code below will log to the console on render and not on click :

```
// Outputs console log on render only
function doSomething() {
    console.log('executed without click event')
}

return(
    <button
      type="button"
      onClick={doSomething()}
    >
)
```

If you’re using Typescript you’ll see an error while typing:

`Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'MouseEventHandler<HTMLButtonElement> | undefined'.`This means we are executing JS **(void)** instead of passing a callback **(MouseEventHandler)** as a value.

Unlike handling HTML DOM events, where you can pass any JS code as a string to `onclick` and it’ll trigger a function when an element is clicked on. For instance:

```
// All work
<button onclick="document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML=1">Click me</button>
<button onclick="console.log('Hi')">Click me</button>
<button onclick="alert('Hi')">Click me</button>
<button onclick="greet()">Click me</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

function greet() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello World";
}
```